# How to Register BHO using C#? What is the parameter i want to send as type?

Tags: c#, dll, bho

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using BHO_HelloWorld;
    using SHDocVw;
  namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
  {
     static class Program
     {
       /// <summary>
       /// The main entry point for the application.
       /// </summary>
       [STAThread]
       static void Main()
       {
            BHO.RegisterBHO(Type);///What is type for that calling?
       }
    }
 }
```

I am calling `BHO.RegisterBHO` function to register BHO. But what is the parameter for this call? What is the `Type` object ?